# Error while saving User in SpringBoot-Neo4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j

I'm trying to save a new user to Neo4j using spring-boot, I'm getting the error that cannot set java.lang.Long to my User domain. Tried a lot of ways but still no luck on this. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
package com.abc.userservice.domains;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private String gender;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String createdOn;

    public User(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(String createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}
```

This is my service code

```
public User createUser(User entity) {
        return userRepository.save(entity);
    }
```

This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User createUser(User user) {
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }
```

This is my main application code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.abc.userservice.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class UserServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I'm trying to save a new user I'm getting this below error:

```
Can not set java.lang.Long field com.abc.userservice.domains.User.id to com.abc.userservice.domains.User
```

Comment: i think u had to use ```GenerationType``` for ur GeneratedValue, like ```@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)```

Comment: ```GenerationType``` is not available for me.

Comment: Can you share the JSON you are sending using REST, my intention is to know if you are passing id with it while saving or it is null?

Comment: @Jatish The main issue was with my pom.xml file.